# Services stopped working - exec: tclsh: not found

Tags: command-line, server, bash

I am running Security Onion on Ubuntu 16.04.  A few of the primary services (SGUIL, PCAP, Snort) stopped working yesterday, 6/9/2019.  In the logs of each of these services I find the following entry:

```
/usr/bin/{service name}_agent.tcl:  line 3:  exec:  tclsh:  not found
```

I see the above message in the following logs:

```
pcap_agent.log
snort_agent.log
squild.log
```

Each of the above logs reference an associated .tcl file in the /usr/bin directory (ie. pcap_agent.tcl, snort_agent.tcl, and sguild).  Each of these files have the following three lines at the very top of the file:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Run tcl from users PATH \
exec tclsh "$0" "$@"
```

I found one forum page that suggested the version of tcl is old and needed to be updated with the `sudo apt-get install tcl` command.  However, when I run that commnand to update it, it states that tcl is already on the newest version (8.6.0+9).

This is the first I've been exposed to .tcl files so I am researching/learning on the fly, and have researched this error extensively on the internet, forums, etc., but have yet to find anything helpful.

Is there anyone who can please help me?  This is impacting our production machine and I need to get this fixed.  I can provide log files, etc. if needed.

Thank you in advance,
Jeff S.

Answer (score 1):

The `exec tclsh` fragment tells your `$SHELL` to look for `tclsh` in each of the directories in your `$PATH` environment variable. Inspect your `$PATH`:

```
echo "$PATH" | tr ":" "\n"
```

`tclsh` is `/usr/bin/tclsh`, so `/usr/bin` must be in your `$PATH` for `exec tclsh` to find it.

`tclsh` is in the `tcl` package:

```
walt@fox:~(0)$ type -p tclsh
/usr/bin/tclsh
walt@fox:~(0)$ dpkg -S $(type -p tclsh)
tcl: /usr/bin/tclsh
walt@fox:~(0)$ dpkg -L tcl
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/tcl
/usr/share/doc/tcl/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/tcl/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/tcl/copyright
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/bin
/usr/share/man/man1/tclsh.1.gz
/usr/bin/tclsh
```

You could reinstall the `tcl` package with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall tcl
```

Comment: thank you for the reply and the advice.  I have verified /usr/bin is in $PATH, and have tried reinstalling the tcl package (both good bits of advice).  The reinstall seemed to go without issue, however now when I start SecurityOnion NSM services, I am still getting the initial error messages, as well as the following new error message:    "update-alternatives:  warning:  forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/bin/tclsh8.6 because link group tclsh is broken"    Any ideas?  Of course I'll keep researching on my end as well.  Thank you!!

Comment: It looks like Security Onion NSM is changing `PATH`

Comment: Waltinator - it appears to be working again.  I haven't been able to pinpoint exactly what the issue was.  But yesterday I applied pending Ubuntu software update packages and rebooted the machine.  After that, all Security Onion services began functioning again.  So at this point I can only deduce the problem was caused by Ubuntu updates that were applied on June 7th (those were the only changes to the machine) and fixed by Ubuntu updates applied on June 17th.  Thank you for your help.